# How to calculate the total distance traveled?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, locationmanager

I have an array list, ArrayList(), which is used to save lat and lng. And then a line will be drawn when there is a new point. I want to get the element inside this array, in order to calculate the total distance. But somehow i use the calculateDistance Method to calculate the total distance, the result is not correct. So i want to know if i had do something wrong.

```
private void whereAmI(){

    Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    //GPS Listener
    manager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);

    //Location Listener
    int minTime = 0;//ms
    int minDist = 0;//meter
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDist, locationListener);
}

GpsStatus.Listener gpsListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_STARTED");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS");
                break;
        }
    }
};

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Out of Service");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Out of Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Available");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

};

private void showMarkerMe(double lat, double lng){
    if (markerMe != null) {
        markerMe.remove();
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    markerOpt.title("I am here!");
    markerMe = mMap.addMarker(markerOpt);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "lat:" + lat + ",lng:" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void cameraFocusOnMe(double lat, double lng){
    CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .zoom(16)
            .build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPosition));
}

private void trackToMe(double lat, double lng){
    if (traceOfMe == null) {
        traceOfMe = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    }
    traceOfMe.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

    calculateDistance(traceOfMe);

    PolylineOptions polylineOpt = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng latlng : traceOfMe) {
        polylineOpt.add(latlng);
    }

    polylineOpt.color(Color.RED);

    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOpt);
    line.setWidth(10);
}

private void calculateDistance(ArrayList<LatLng> points) {

    for (int i =0; i < points.size() -1; i++) {
        LatLng pointA =  points.get(i);
        LatLng pointB = points.get(i + 1);
        float[] results = new float[3];
        Location.distanceBetween (pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
        totalD +=  results[0];
    }
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

    String where = "";
    if (location != null) {

        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        double lat = location.getLatitude();

        float speed = location.getSpeed();

        long time = location.getTime();
        String timeString = getTimeString(time);

        speedList.add(""+ speed);

        where = "Lng: " + lng +
                "  Lat: " + lat +
                "  Speed: " + speed +
                "\nTime: " + timeString +
                "  Provider: " + "gps" +
                "  Distance: " + totalD ;


        showMarkerMe(lat, lng);
        cameraFocusOnMe(lat, lng);
        trackToMe(lat, lng);

    }else{
        where = "No location found.";
    }


    txt.setText(where);
}
```

Comment: you say the results is wrong how wrong they are? can you gives some example

Comment: when i walked in a 140m long route, the distance calculated was 9950m, but somehow the path drawn is correct. So i wanna know if my logic of using the above code is wrong

Comment: ;) that is too much, I give it a look but it might take some time and get back

Comment: so Levon answer but got my vote for question and answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the `totalD` variable is declared, but it seems like it is accumulating values with each point you add to the list. Say you walk from point A to point B with a distance of 10 meters, so your initial ArrayList contains only 2 points and when you calculate the distance it is correctly calculated as 10 meters and assigned to totalD variable. Now you walk further, from point B to point C, say another 5 meters, and  your ArrayList now contains 3 points A, B, and C, with a total distance that's supposed to be 15 meters (10 + 5). The way your function was written, you go through the list of points, and add it all to totalD without ever re-setting it. So, your totalD already had a value of 10 from the previous calculation, and now by going through the ArrayList again and getting a total of 15, you add that 15 to the previous 10 that you had there from the first calculation. Your totalD is now 25 (10 + 15, the results of all previous calculations combined), instead of simply 15 (the result of only the last calculation). So in your `calculateDistance()` method instead of

```
totalD +=  results[0];
```

you should have a local variable, say `tempTotalDistance`, and then add all distances between points into it, and then assign its final value to your global `totalD`. Your new `calculateDistance()` can look something like this:

```
private void calculateDistance(ArrayList<LatLng> points) {

    float tempTotalDistance;

    for (int i =0; i < points.size() -1; i++) {
        LatLng pointA =  points.get(i);
        LatLng pointB = points.get(i + 1);
        float[] results = new float[3];
        Location.distanceBetween (pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
        tempTotalDistance +=  results[0];
    }

    totalD = tempTotalDistance;
}
```

Comment: i declare the totalD as a global variable float totalD = 0f; , do i need to initialize the tempTotalDistance as 0 first? Can you tell what is the different between your answer and my code, pls?? As i want to know the logic behind, thz a lot

Comment: I updated the answer with a detailed explanation. You can assign 0f to your floats when you declare them. If my answer is correct, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @Levon Can you look at this one.Is there anything wrong with my calaculation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361131/how-to-find-the-distance-traveled-in-kilometers-by-following-gps-co-ordinates-us?noredirect=1#comment68011278_40361131

Comment: @Noufal The link is broken, couldn't find the post you linked to

Comment: @Levon This is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481242/the-geo-cordinates-getting-is-very-far-from-previous-one